# Oracle use a hint index to a view and force it to base table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, query-optimization

How to  use a hint on a query against a view to force Oracle to use an index on the base table?

E.g

View

```
select emp_id 
from v_employees
```

base table

```
select emp_id /*+ INDEX(employees IDX_emp_id) */ 
from employees
```

I want to read from the view but use the index from the base table, without changing the view query. Something like this:

```
select emp_id /*+ INDEX(v_employees employees IDX_emp_id) */
from v_employees
```

Comment: I want to select from the view but use an index from the base table.

Comment: i am asking how to select from the view but use an index from the base table

Comment: i am asking how to do it without changing the view query

Answer (score 3):

We can use global hints to reference the tables inside views. The view name is nested with the table name(s) or alias(es) (if we want to access indexes on tables in subqueries) using `.`.

So in your example it would be:

```
select /*+ INDEX(v_employees.employees IDX_emp_id) */ emp_id 
from v_employees
```

Note that the hint comes before the projection.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm)

> You can send hints for a SQL statement to the optimizer by enclosing
>   them in a comment within the statement.
>
> A block in a statement can have only one comment containing hints
>   following the SELECT, UPDATE, MERGE, or DELETE keyword.

```
SELECT /*+ hint [text] [hint[text]]... */ COLUMNS... FROM TABLE....
```

So in you case, Use the Hint following the `SELECT` keyword.

```
select /*+ INDEX(employees IDX_emp_id) */ emp_id  from employees
```

Cheers!!

Comment: The question isn't completely clear but it seems the Seeker wants to use an index hint when querying **a view** not the table underlying the view.

Comment: That's correct, i want to know how use an index hint when querying a view not the underlying table

Comment: This does beg the question of why? Why do you need to use a hint?